# Cocoa: NSTimer gdb when invalidating

Tags: cocoa, gdb, nstimer, invalidation

I'm using some timers and want the user to be able to cancel it before it's done, or remove it from a view after it has finished. Both of these things are supposed to be handled by a cancelAction method. If the timer hasn't finished, an if statement in cancelAction tells the timers to invalidate, makes them nil and removes the view displaying the time left. This works perfectly. If the timers already finished, cancelAction only removes the view, and does not try to invalidate them. But this doesn't seem to work. If I cancel before they finish, everything works, If I cancel after they finished, it throws an exception saying unrecognized selector sent to instance. Both timer were made using the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method

The difference between calling before or after they finished, is that if they finished, this method is run.

```
- (void)timerFinished:(id)sender {
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
[timerLabelUpdater invalidate];
timerLabelUpdater = nil;
}
```

This is where it gets strange. If I just remove `[timerLaberUpdater invalidate]` the method gets called and it gets removed. I don't want to remove that line because that timer counts down the time left and updates the view with the time left. If I don't invalidate it, it keeps counting down to the negatives, plus it takes up memory.

I sincerely have no idea why removing that line changes anything, both timers were called in the same way, and if I remove the other line, it still doesn't work, ONLY by removing that instruction does anything change.

I get EXC BAD ACCESS in gdb, which I think means the selector is sent to an instance that was released.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your timer is not _autorepeating_ it will be invalidated as soon as it finishes. In addition to that, the run loop will release it so you might end up with an unallocated instance that unsurpisingly throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought was happening, how can i release them from the run loop but prevent the instance from deallocating?

Comment: Well, you should retain your timer when you create it via the -[scheduledTimer...] method so that when you call invalidate it doesn't get deallocated by the autoreleasepool and you can release it on your own. Or, you can try creating your timer via the instance init method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([timerLabelUpdater isValid])
    [timerLabelUpdater invalidate];
```